# Can't control the ::after when input is :valid

Tags: html, css

**Can't seem to control the `div::after` when the input inside is `:valid`.**

Can someone help?
https://jsfiddle.net/Mengolor/0akjcsvf/

```css
input.your-name {
 height: auto;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid lightgray;
 border-radius: 2px;
 padding: 24px 0px 4px 4px;
}

div.nf-field-element::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 29px;
 left: 12px;
  content: "Example";
 color: black;
 font-size: 100%;
 transition: 0.2s;
}

div.nf-field-element:focus-within::after {
 top: 14px;
 color: lightgray;
 font-size: 70%;
}

input:focus {
 outline: none;
}

input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

/* CSS ONLY | When the field is filled the 'Example' label should stay up */
```

```html
<div class="nf-field-element">
  <input type="text" class="your-name" placeholder=" " required>
</div>
```

FYI, can't change the HTML code

If JS is the solution, how would be the script?
I have no experience with JS

Lorenzo

Comment: There is no parent element selector in CSS, so I think given that you can not change the HTML it can't be done using just CSS.

Comment: How easy would be to solve this with JS?

Comment: I never did something like this and I'm sure there is a better way but I added an answer with some example code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do it using pseudo selector.

If you want, you can add a `label` instead and with the following code you'll have the desired behaviour:

```html
<div class="nf-field-element">
  <input type="text" class="your-name" placeholder=" " required>
  <label>Example</label>
</div>
```

```css
label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  left: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

div.nf-field-element:focus-within label,
input:valid + label {
 top: 14px;
 color: lightgray;
 font-size: 70%;
}
```

Here is [an working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ionut_t/d9406xvn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achive the desired effect with a bit of javascript. The way this works is we add an event listener to each text-input element. Depending on its validity we add or remove the class "valid" on its parent element. We can then simply target the `:after` element using a selector like `div.nf-field-element.valid::after`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.classList[e.target.validity.valid ? "add" : "remove"]("valid");
  });
});
```

```css
input.your-name {
 height: auto;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid lightgray;
 border-radius: 2px;
 padding: 24px 0px 4px 4px;
}

div.nf-field-element::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 29px;
 left: 12px;
  content: "Example";
 color: black;
 font-size: 100%;
 transition: 0.2s;
}

div.nf-field-element.valid::after,
div.nf-field-element:focus-within::after {
 top: 14px;
 color: lightgray;
 font-size: 70%;
}

input:focus {
 outline: none;
}

input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

/* CSS ONLY | When the field is filled the 'Example' label should stay up */
```

```html
<div class="nf-field-element">
  <input type="text" class="your-name" placeholder=" " required>
</div>
```